# Codeigniter page not found with trailing slash in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-3

I am using codeiginiter where I have a form like so:

```
<form action="announcements/submit_announcement" method="post" id="announcement_form">
```

Where `announcements` is my controller.

If I am at www.mysite.com/home and I submit the form it works properly. However, if I am at www.mysite.com/home/ it will append the text above the end, resulting in www.mysite.com/home/announcements/submit_announcement.

It will then get a page not found.

What is going on here? Shouldn't codeiginiter have this in mind and not have this happen? Disappointed in this..

Does anybody have a fix for this?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with CodeIgniter, PHP, or even the `form` `action`.  This is the normal behavior of a relative URL.  Try the absolute URL instead:  `action="/announcements/submit_announcement"`

Answer (score 1):

Just use codeigniter form_open() it makes things so much easier. 
In application/autoload in helpers include form to load automatically or load in your controller

$this->load->helper('form');

then in your view

```
echo form_open('announcements/submit_announcement','id="announcement_form"');
```

Note that I passed your id in there as a string but you can also include a variable for an array, like if you are using bootstrap and want to add a class.

more in the manual: 
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open
note that reading the manual might save you more "disappointment" :-)

Comment: _"note that reading the manual might save you more 'disappointment'"_ ~ I'll second that.  As per the manual, the base URL is appended to the specified action, ensuring an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Use following instead what you using now

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('announcements/submit_announcement');?>" method="post" id="announcement_form">
```

and now test

Comment: What you have set your `$config['base_url']` in config.php ?